# Pyplot set_xscale('log') hides ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I have a plot with an Axes, and I call:

```
axes.set_xscale('log')
```

After that I cannot see any tick label along the x axis, when I use `axes.set_xticks(my_ticks)`. Without the `log` I can see the tick labels.

How can I show my ticks on the log scale?

Comment: Could you please provide a full example showing the problem? Otherwise, it is difficult to guess where your problem comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axes.set_xticks(my_ticks)` sets the position of the ticks, it normally automatically updates the tick labels, but it seems it doesn't. You can use [set_xticklabels()](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) to set them yourself.
You can use [tick_params()](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) to change properties of the ticks (like length, color etc) themselves.